# How to get dart2js javascript that uses canvas.context2D to work on firefox or safari?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I have program that seems to compile with dart2js enough for UI such as checkbox working, and even can do

```dart
CanvasRenderingContext2D context=canvas.context2D;

context
..setFillColorRgb(200,200,250,1)
..beginPath()
..fillRect(0,0,width, height)
..closePath();
```

on firefox, ( not Safari).

But it won't do

```dart
context
..setStrokeColorRgb(255,0,255)
..lineWidth=10
..beginPath()
..arc(w/2,h/2, r, 0, math.PI*2, false)
..closePath()
..stroke()
```

It works on Chrome, and chromium ( native dart). 
How to fix ?

Comment: This worked for me on chrome, firefox, and safari. Can you restate the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I used context.resetTranform() , after removing this statement, it worked on 
Safari chrome and firefox.